# Ask for file name before saving it

Tags: excel, vba

I have following code, which Saves file automatically as per my desired output, I want to make 2 changes into it

1. ask for file name, currently it saves automatically with "Carrier Files"
2. copy sheets from 5th sheet to last sheet

```
Sub Splitbook()
Dim xWs As Worksheet
Dim xPath As String

xPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Carrier Files"

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

For Each xWs In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    xWs.UsedRange.Value = xWs.UsedRange.Value
Next xWs

Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=xPath & "" & AD & ".xlsx"

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Sheets("NIFTY WEEK ALL").Select

MsgBox ("Done.")

End Sub
```

Comment: Look at the GetSaveAsFileName method: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Application.GetSaveAsFilename

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To ask for the filename you could use a simple InputBox like so:

```
xPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
AD = InputBox("Enter desired filename")
Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=xPath & "\" & AD & ".xlsm"
```

To copy sheet 5:

```
Sheets(5).Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
```

Comment: all data pasted in new sheet is pasting it with conditional format as well, whereas I just want it to paste as value only, can you pls provide solution to this?

Comment: `Sheets(Sheets.Count).Cells.FormatConditions.Delete`

Answer (score -1):

Use a `Inputbox()` for file name to enter. Try below sub

```
Sub Splitbook()
Dim xWs As Worksheet
Dim xPath As String
Dim myFile As String

    xPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Carrier Files\"
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    For Each xWs In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        myFile = InputBox("Enter a file name to save", "File Name", xWs.Name) 'Input file name
        xWs.UsedRange.Value = xWs.UsedRange.Value
    Next xWs
    
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=xPath & myFile & ".xlsm"

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Sheets("NIFTY WEEK ALL").Select

    MsgBox ("Done.")

End Sub
```